# Can k=len(vocab) be used with top_k when viewing predicted tokens?

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

When viewing the top predicted tokens in masked language modelling (MLM), is it possible to use `top_k` with `k=len(vocab)`?

So far, I have used this following line of code:

```
mask_filler("The capital of [MASK] is Paris", top_k=5)
```

Would it be possible to incorporate `k=len(vocab)` into the line of code above to see the predicted tokens in my vocabulary or not?

Comment: Where does the `mask_filler` come from? It does not sound like something one could find in the Hugginngface Transformers API.

Comment: Hello, I found it here: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-test-masked-language-model-after-training-it/7029